# angularjs how can i post my form into the json

Tags: angularjs, json, forms, post

I am building my first angular app and looking to post my form into my JSON data.

This is my form:

```
  <span ng-show="show">
  <form name="inputForm" class="form-group" ng-controller="FormController as autoctrl"  ng-submit="inputForm.$valid && autoctrl.addGegevens(gegeven)" novalidate>
  <br>

  <p> Type: <input type="text" name="type" ng-model="type" style="margin-left:52px; padding-left:5px;  width:165px;" minlength="2" maxlength="10" required /></p>

  <p>Bouwjaar: <input type="number" name="bouwjaar" ng-model="bouwjaar"  style="margin-left:22px; padding-left:5px;  width:165px;" minlength="4" maxlength="4" required /></p>

  <p>Km: <input type="number" name="km" ng-model="km" style="margin-left:60px; padding-left:5px;  width:165px;" minlength="2" maxlength="6" required /></p>

  <p>Brandstof:  <input id="select" name="brandstof" ng-model="brandstof" style="margin-left:20px; padding-left:5px;" minlength="3" maxlength="7" required/></p>

  <p>Kenteken: <input type="text" name="kenteken" ng-model="kenteken" style="margin-left:22px; padding-left:5px; width:165px;" minlength="6" maxlength="9" required /></p>

  <p>Datum:  <input type="text" name="datum" ng-model="datum"  style="margin-left:40px; padding-left:5px;  width:165px;" minlength="3" maxlength="11" required  /></p>

  <p>checked: <input type="checkbox"  name="checked" ng-model="checked" style="margin-left:28px;" required /></p>

   <br>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"    value="submit">Toevoegen</button>

   <div>{{inputForm.$valid}}</div>


  </form>
  </span>
```

And this is my app.js:

```
(function(){
var volkswagenApp = angular.module('volkswagenapp',[]);


 volkswagenApp.controller('VolkswagenCtrl', [ '$http' ,       function($http){
         var vw =  this;
         vw.gegevens = [];
         $http.get('autos.json').success(function(data){
         vw.gegevens = data;
         });



        }]);

        volkswagenApp.controller('FormController',function(){
           this.gegevens={};
          /* this.addGegevens = function(gegeven) {
            gegeven.gegevens.push(this.gegeven);
            this.gegevens={};
           }*/

           this.addGegevens = function(gegeven){
            this.gegevens.datum = Date.now();
            vw.gegevens.push(this.gegeven);
            this.gegeven = {};
           }


                });

                })();
```

Can somebody tell me where I am going wrong? I did the same steps as they do on codeschool.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `controllerAs` you need to add the controller object to all the variables in `ng-model`

Example:

```
<input  name="type" ng-model="type">
```

Should be:

```
<input  name="type" ng-model="autoctrl.type">
```

However you can make it simpler to post a single object by making all the `ng-model`'s properties of the same parent

```
<input  name="type" ng-model="autoctrl.myFormModel.type">
```

Then when you are ready to post you simply send `myFormModel`

```
$http.post(url, this.myFormModel).then(....
```

Note that you should store a reference to `this` so you can use that reference inside any callbacks. I see you using `vm` but it is not defined anywhere inside `FormController`

See [John Papa Angular Style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#style-y032)

Comment: Error: Can't find variable: vw
addGegevens@http://localhost:8888/volkswagen2/app.js:24:19
fn
b@http://localhost:8888/volkswagen2/angular/angular.min.js:126:129
e@http://localhost:8888/volkswagen2/angular/angular.min.js:276:196
$eval@http://localhost:8888/volkswagen2/angular/angular.min.js:145:347
$apply@http://localhost:8888/volkswagen2/angular/angular.min.js:146:57
http://localhost:8888/volkswagen2/angular/angular.min.js:276:253
Sf@http://localhost:8888/volkswagen2/angular/angular.min.js:37:131
d@http://localhost:8888/volkswagen2/angular/angular.min.js:37:75

Comment: this is my error, i tried everything to do the post but im just not getting it